# How can I get id of dropdownlistfor's item without button

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Currently I have a dropwdownlist and ı need to get the id of selecteditem in dropdownlist which is CheckListTypeId.CheckList is my model's list and ı added 4 section in this list.When ı select one of them it need to bring that section's elements which is item in db.

ı tried to use request to db but ım not sure its correct.I hope you can help me.I m going to use this items in foreach loop in view.

Here is my view :

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
    <table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
    <td>@Html.Label("PersonalAdı")  </td>
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.PersonalName) </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FormDetail.CheckListType)</td>         
   <td>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => 
  model.FormDetail.CheckListTypeId, Model.checkLists, new { @onchange =  
  " createlement(this.value);" })
        </td>

    </tr>

 string selvalue = Request[Model.FormDetail.CheckListTypeId.ToString()];
int id = Convert.ToInt32(selvalue);
TodoAppEntities db = Tools.GetConnection();
ItemsRepository items = new ItemsRepository();
CheckListRepository checkListRep = new CheckListRepository();
List<CheckList> checkLists = db.CheckLists.Where(t => t.CheckListTypeId == 
id).ToList();

foreach (CheckList item in checkLists)
{
    List<Item> İtemList = db.Items.Where(t => t.ItemId == 
item.ItemId).ToList();

}
```

Controller:

```
       FormDetailViewModel model = new FormDetailViewModel();
        foreach(Form item in formRep.List().ProcessResult)
        {
            FormList.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = 
  item.FormId.ToString(), Text = item.TeslimEden });
        }
        foreach(Item item in itemRep.List().ProcessResult)
        {
            İtemList.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = 
  item.ItemId.ToString(), Text = item.ItemDesc });
        }
        foreach(CheckListType item in typeRep.List().ProcessResult)
        {
            TypeList.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = 
 item.CheckListTypeId.ToString(), Text = item.CheckListType1 });
        }



        model.checkLists = TypeList;
        model.FormViewList = FormList;
        model.İtems = İtemList;

        return View(model);
```

selvalue return null and ı dont know how to get id of items.

Comment: If I'm understanding the question, you want to load items based on what is selected in the dropdown.  Unless you post the form back to the controller with a button, you will need to use javascript (or jquery, etc) to bind a function to the dropdown, and then call the controller (to get the list from the db/service/whatever) and you will then need to use javascript for the UI (hide/show/ create new ui elements, etc)..

Comment: Yes I'm trying to load items of section and user will answer the questions and send the form to db.I m not clearly understand controller part.